# "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" equivalent for a Windows Phone 7 TextBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to get a TextBox in Windows Phone 7 to update the Binding as the user types each letter rather than after losing focus?

Like the following WPF TextBox would do:

```xaml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TextProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: +1 for asking one of the most common WP problems

Comment: And still missing in WP8 :(

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Silverlight for WP7 does not support the syntax you've listed. Do the following instead:

```xaml
<TextBox TextChanged="OnTextBoxTextChanged"
         Text="{Binding MyText, Mode=TwoWay,
                UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
```

> `UpdateSourceTrigger = Explicit` is a smart bonus here. **What is it?** [Explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx): Updates the binding source only when you call the `UpdateSource` method. It saves you one extra binding set when the user leaves the `TextBox`.

In C#:

```cs
private void OnTextBoxTextChanged( object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e )
{
  TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
  // Update the binding source
  BindingExpression bindingExpr = textBox.GetBindingExpression( TextBox.TextProperty );
  bindingExpr.UpdateSource();
}
```

Comment: Solved "The one specific" issue related to binding using the above "BindingExpression" code. Tons of thanks for making my code happy.

Answer (score 23):

I like using an attached property. Just in case you're into those little buggers.

```
<toolkit:DataField Label="Name">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Product.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" c:BindingUtility.UpdateSourceOnChange="True"/>
</toolkit:DataField>
```

And then the backing code.

```
public class BindingUtility
{
public static bool GetUpdateSourceOnChange(DependencyObject d)
{
  return (bool)d.GetValue(UpdateSourceOnChangeProperty);
}

public static void SetUpdateSourceOnChange(DependencyObject d, bool value)
{
  d.SetValue(UpdateSourceOnChangeProperty, value);
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for …
public static readonly DependencyProperty
  UpdateSourceOnChangeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "UpdateSourceOnChange",
    typeof(bool),
              typeof(BindingUtility),
    new PropertyMetadata(false, OnPropertyChanged));

private static void OnPropertyChanged (DependencyObject d,
  DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var textBox = d as TextBox;
  if (textBox == null)
    return;
  if ((bool)e.NewValue)
  {
    textBox.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
  }
  else
  {
    textBox.TextChanged -= OnTextChanged;
  }
}
static void OnTextChanged(object s, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var textBox = s as TextBox;
  if (textBox == null)
    return;

  var bindingExpression = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
  if (bindingExpression != null)
  {
    bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Be careful using this technique, it can introduce Memory Leaks as the event handler is never deregistered. http://sharpfellows.com/post/Memory-Leaks-and-Dependency-Properties.aspx

Comment: @FlatlinerDOA : In this case there is no risk of memory leak because the reference is from the non-static object (TextBox) to the static event handler (BindingUtility.OnTextChanged). The problem would have been if the reference was the other way around.

Comment: @Parrhesia Joe , i have attached behavior in most of my toolkit text-box, In a textbox i have used `<toolkit:PhoneTextBox Hint="Last 10 Digit Card Number"
    Grid.Row="0" 
                InputScope="Number"
                MaxLength="10"                  
    DisplayedMaxLength="10" 
                Text="{Binding CardNumber,Mode=TwoWay}"
                ActionIcon="/Assets/Help.png"
                helpers:BindingUtility.UpdateSourceOnChange="True"
                KeyDown="PhoneTextBox_KeyDown"/>` this has some issues , seems like cursor goes to first item when i press 0

Answer (score 5):

Not through binding syntax, no, but it's easy enough without. You have to handle the TextChanged event and call [UpdateSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatesource(v=vs.95).aspx) on the binding.

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox) sender).GetBindingExpression( TextBox.TextProperty ).UpdateSource();
}
```

This can be converted into an [attached behavior](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johngossman/archive/2008/05/07/the-attached-behavior-pattern.aspx) as well pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

In TextChanged event call [UpdateSource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatesource.aspx).

```
BindingExpression be = itemNameTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
be.UpdateSource();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own TextBox Behavior to handle Update on TextChanged:

This is my sample to PasswordBox but you can simple change it to handle any property of the any object.

```
public class UpdateSourceOnPasswordChangedBehavior
     : Behavior<PasswordBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged += OnPasswordChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged -= OnPasswordChanged;
    }

    private void OnPasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(PasswordBox.PasswordProperty).UpdateSource();
    }
}
```

Ussage:

```xaml
<PasswordBox x:Name="Password" Password="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}" >
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <common:UpdateSourceOnPasswordChangedBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</PasswordBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit doesnt work for me, hence Im using custom class derivated from TextBox

```
public class TextBoxEx : TextBox
{
    public TextBoxEx()
    {
        TextChanged += (sender, args) =>
                           {
                               var bindingExpression = GetBindingExpression(TextProperty);
                               if (bindingExpression != null)
                               {
                                   bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
                               }
                           };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just one line of code!

```
(sender as TextBox).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
```

You can create a generic TextChanged event (for example "ImmediateTextBox_TextChanged")  in the code behind of your page, and than link it to any TextBox in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I took [Praetorian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4833196/1366033) and made an extension class that inherits `TextBox` so you don't have to muddle up your view's code behind with this behavior.

**C-Sharp**:

```cs
public class TextBoxUpdate : TextBox
{
    public TextBoxUpdate()
    {
        TextChanged += OnTextBoxTextChanged;
    }
    private void OnTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox senderText = (TextBox)sender;
        BindingExpression bindingExp = senderText.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        bindingExp.UpdateSource();
    }
}
```

**VisualBasic**:

```vb
Public Class TextBoxUpdate : Inherits TextBox

    Private Sub OnTextBoxTextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.TextChanged
        Dim senderText As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
        Dim bindingExp As BindingExpression = senderText.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty)
        bindingExp.UpdateSource()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then call like this in **XAML**:

```xaml
<local:TextBoxUpdate Text="{Binding PersonName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```