# How to MVVMCross trigger binding on typing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, mvvmcross

I am trying to bind the value of a textbox as the "filter" for a query. I want the query to run without having the user have to click submit.

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="False" Name="FilterTextBox" Width="250" TextChanged="FilterTextBox_OnTextChanged" Text="{Binding Filter, Mode=TwoWay}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Padding="12,0,0,10"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was remove the two way binding to make sure there was no overlap of the update

```
 <TextBox IsReadOnly="False" Name="FilterTextBox" Width="250" TextChanged="FilterTextBox_OnTextChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Padding="12,0,0,10"/>
```

and cast the ViewModel in the code behind to the proper view model and performed the method

```
 private void FilterTextBox_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((DictionaryViewModel) ViewModel).Filter = FilterTextBox.Text;
    }
```

I would be curious to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: This is the long established way that WPF/Silverlight textboes work - you might try things like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569768/textbox-binding-twoway-doesnt-update-until-focus-lost-wp7, http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2009/12/24/make-a-silverlight-textbox-update-its-binding-on-every-character.aspx and http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/n35-multibinding-with-tibet-n1-videos.html