# Metro Style Apps Two way Binding with XML

Tags: microsoft-metro

Can I do two way binding with an XML document in metro style apps (using WPF/C#)? I want my XML file to get updated as soon as I make a change on the UI

Answer (score 0):

Sure. After update invoke your method that will update your xml file. It won`t work automaticly, you need to manage this yourself

Comment: Right, but I want to do it automatically. This was possible in WPF apps I guess...I was wondering if this is achievable in metro style apps or not? Actually, I want to have auto-save feature in my app

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about XAML's Mode=TwoWay binding (default is Mode=OneWay), but I think you really mean UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged (as in WPF) which in WinRT is a bit of a trick. Answer is here: [“UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged” equivalent for a TextBox in WinRT-XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692885/updatesourcetrigger-propertychanged-equivalent-for-a-windows-8-textbox)

Answer (score 0):

may be u can call the saveXML() method on 'textChanged' event of the textboxes or any other UI controls of your metro app...