# WinRT TextBox MaxLength does not count \n\r as two characters

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have `TextBox` with `MaxLength` set to 10 but it is accepting 11 characters when Enter key is pressed. Looks like it is counting *\n\r* as 1 character instead of two. Is there anyway to make it count *\n\r* as two char length?

Comment: Pretty hard to imagine a multi-line textbox accepting only 10 chars being useful.  My crystal ball says that you forgot to set the AcceptsReturn property to False.

Comment: Line breaks are indeed unlikely in a 10 character string, but the question is still relevant for higher numbers. (And why not allowing line breaks in a text which, let's say, will be stored in a fixed-size `char(10)` DB column?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to allow line breaks in your text box and limit its text length, I see two options:

- Either bind `MaxLength` through a converter so that it changes its value according to how many line breaks (`\r\n`) the text contains, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732782/handling-maxlength-via-binding)
- Alternatively, you might define your own attached property `MaxLength` that calculates text length correctly. This might look somewhat like the following (just as an example you'll need to adapt that to take into account special cases etc.):

  ```
  public class TextBoxExtensions: DependencyObject
  {
      public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxLengthProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
          "MaxLength", typeof (int), typeof (MaxLengthBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(int), PropertyChangedCallback));

      public static void SetMaxLength(DependencyObject element, int value)
      {
          element.SetValue(MaxLengthProperty, value);
      }

      public static int GetMaxLength(DependencyObject element)
      {
          return (int) element.GetValue(MaxLengthProperty);
      }

      private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
      {
          var tb = dependencyObject as TextBox;
          if (tb != null)
          {
              tb.KeyDown -= TbOnKeyDown;
              tb.KeyDown += TbOnKeyDown;
          }
      }

      private static void TbOnKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs args)
      {
          var tb = sender as TextBox;
          if (tb != null)
          {
              int max = GetMaxLength(tb);
              if (tb.Text.Length >= max)
                  args.Handled = true;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

`<TextBox local:TextBoxExtensions.MaxLength="10" />`