# UpdateSourceTrigger for multiple fields

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding

Based on:

["UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" equivalent for a Windows Phone 7 TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833100/updatesourcetrigger-propertychanged-equivalent-for-a-windows-phone-7-textbox)

If my app have 100 textbox that needs to update their sources, Do I Have to use the code to update them all?

```
TextBlock1.GetBindingExpression(TexBlock.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
TextBlock2.GetBindingExpression(TexBlock.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
```

...

```
TextBlock100.GetBindingExpression(TexBlock.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
```

I would like to do it **without VisualTree**. Something like to set the update to the parent object with a DataContext.

Comment: I don't get it. Just put the exact same `OnTextBoxTextChanged` method as in the question linked, and assign it to the `TextChanged` event handler of each of your textbox. The `sender` argument is used so that the appropriate textbox will be updated, without having to write a specific line of code for each.