# TextBox custom space between group of letters (for phone number)

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone-7, textbox

I have this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txbPhone" Text="+420" 
         InputScope="TelephoneNumber" Margin="9,0,9,0"/>
```

Now I want to user to write his phone number like:
`+420123456789` I want to show it in TextBox like `+420 123 456 789`
I am thinking about create it by manual adding spaces in code when user change value of TextBox. Then when I used it I just remove all spaces in string. But I think it's little "dirty" solution. Is there a way how can I set some template for this? Thanks

**Edit:**
I create Converter as mention `Frederik Winstrup Johansen` in comment. So I created my class (it needs add code to ConvertBack method):

```
public class PhoneNumberConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var str = (string)value;
        string result;
        if (str[0] == '+')
            result = String.Format("{0:+### ### ### ###}", System.Convert.ToInt64(value));
        else
            result = String.Format("{0:### ### ### ###}", (Int64)value);
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

and changed my TextBox to:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txbPhone" Text="{Binding Path=Phone, Converter={StaticResource phoneNumberConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                 InputScope="TelephoneNumber" Margin="9,0,9,0" TextChanged="txbPhone_TextChanged"/>
```

This is my binding:

```
        viewModel = new PhonePageViewModel();
        viewModel.Phone = "+420123456";
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
```

Converter is working but it's not changing text when I add some numbers. There are no calling for Convert method again. How can I do this? Everytime when I changed letter in TextBox call Converter?

My viewmodel class:

```
namespace SpeedCarsWP.ViewModels
{
    public class PhonePageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string phone;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string Phone
        {
            get { return phone; }
            set
            {
                phone = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Phone");
            }
        }

        public PhonePageViewModel()
        {
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: If you bind the value (the phone number), you can use a converter with the binding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a solution with databinding + converter, implement this and it will work for you. (I tried it and it worked.)

**First**, in the View the XAML-Part:

```
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,60,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
             Text="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" 
             TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged" />
```

**UpdateSourceTrigger** stands for formatting the text character by character.

**Second**, the ViewModel-Part:

By MyProperty in VM you need to use **NotifyPropertyChanged** to trigger update.
(If you don't do this Convert-Method of the Converter will be run just once, only at the first time.)

**Third**, the Converter-Part:

You can implement a converter body like:

```
        if (value != null)
        {
            string str = value.ToString();
            string result = str;

            if (str.Length == 1)
            {
                result = str.Insert(0, "+");
            }
            if (str.Length == 5 || (str.Length > 5 && (str.Length -1) % 4 == 0))
            {
                result = str.Insert(str.Length-1, " ");
            }

            return result;
        }
        return value;
```

If you do this, the textbox cursor will be not at the end of the text, so you need to correct it from code-behind of your View.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
    }
```

It is just a rapid implementation thinking in solution with Converter but I hope it could help you.

Comment: Looks that this solution could work but I have error: Requested value PropertyChanged not found. But I implement in my viewmodel class INotifyPropertyChanged. I edited code above and added my viewmodel class. I think there could be problem with namespaces. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: The textbox, you mentioned above not contains UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged. Is it so or you just not updated it?

Comment: I don't updated it but I added. That's where I have that error.

Comment: Sorry it was my fault. In WP7 you dont have UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged by default. You need to implement it and you can find the way to do it on this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833100/updatesourcetrigger-propertychanged-equivalent-for-a-windows-phone-7-textbox)

Comment: And now it's working. I just must change that format string that numbers would start fill from left but it's other problem. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

> Converter is working but it's not changing text when I add some
>   numbers. There are no calling for Convert method again. How can I do
>   this? Everytime when I changed letter in TextBox call Converter?

The converter should be updated automatically.

Are you sure that you `PhonePageViewModel` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`?
Do you raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the `PhonePageViewModel.Phone` setter?

Do you have binding errors ? (check the Ouput pane in Visual Studio when debugging).