# Instantly Update Property in MVVM Light?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a property in my View Model

```
public const string WelcomeTitlePropertyName = "WelcomeTitle";

    private string _welcomeTitle = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the WelcomeTitle property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public string WelcomeTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return _welcomeTitle;
        }

        set
        {
            RaisePropertyChanging(WelcomeTitlePropertyName);
            _welcomeTitle = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(WelcomeTitlePropertyName);
        }
    }
```

This is hooked up to a textbox and has 2 way binding.

Now I have a KeyDown event that I need to get the current length of the "WelcomeTitle" property

```
  public ICommand AutoComplete
        {
            get
            {
               return new RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs>(e =>
                {
                    var length = WelcomeTitle.Length;
               });
            }
        }
```

Yep what I am finding is that WelcomeTitle property does not get updated till the user leaves the textbox. This does not work for me as I need to know the length(and later the current value in WelcomeTitle) and keydown.

How can I get around this? In codebehind this is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF it would be easily achieved by setting `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` in the binding; unfortunately, this is not possible with Windows Phone, so you need a workaround. A few options are described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833100/updatesourcetrigger-propertychanged-equivalent-for-a-windows-phone-7-textbox).

Comment: hmm where would I stick that code from those options? In keypress down?

Comment: In the TextChanged event of the TextBox

Comment: An event handler in the code behind (you can't access the TextBox from the ViewModel anyway)

Comment: This seems to work but I had to change the event to KeyUp instead of KeyDown as it still does not work on KeyDown.

Comment: @chobo2, you should handle the TextChanged event rather than KeyUp or KeyDown

Comment: Sorry not following you. I should make a RelayCommand for TextChanged and then make a code behind event for TextChanged as well? What is the exact difference between textchanged and keyDown/Up

Comment: Who said anything about a RelayCommand for TextChanged? You just need an event handler for TextChanged that will update the binding source. In the setter of your viewmodel's property, you can then detect that the property has changed, and do whatever you need to do there.

Comment: It probably is not clear from my stripped down example but what I have is a property(WelcomeText) that stores the textbox value entered, I then have in keypress code to hit my server to grab all possible words for autocomplete based on user input. Are you saying I should move that server hit code to the TextChanged codebehind event?

Comment: OK, I think there are two things being mixed up here... In my view, you don't need the `AutoComplete` command at all, because you can detect any change to the text in the property setter. However, you still have the issue that this property isn't updated until the focus leaves the TextBox. The `TextChanged` event handler I'm talking about addresses *that* problem, not the call to the server

Comment: hmm I get what your saying the only thing I am not sure about how to do would be ignoring spaces and backspaces entered in. If someone is making a space to separate 2 words I don't want to do a server request as the result will be the same.