# String bound to TextBox is not updating

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I've got a `TextBox` and a search `Button` which has to be enabled only if the `TextBox` is not empty.

Since I'm using `MVVM Light`, I've bound the button to a `RelayCommand` which has a `CanExecute` function which just returns a boolean value.

Here's the `Button`'s code:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="1" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNoPadding}" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}">
    <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Width="40" Height="40" >
        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Assets/AppBar/feature.search.png" />
        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
    </Rectangle>
</Button>
```

and here's the `Command` and the property returned by the `CanExecute` function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Boolean that enables/disables the search button
/// </summary>
public bool CanSearch
{
    get
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchQuery) && NetworkUtils.IsNetworkAvailable;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Command used to search for data
/// </summary>
private RelayCommand _searchCommand;
public RelayCommand SearchCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _searchCommand ?? new RelayCommand(ExecuteSearch, () => CanSearch);
    }
}
```

Now, as you may have noticed, the `CanSearch` property depends on the lenght of the `SearchQuery` string.

The problem here is that this string is always null until I go back and load the page again.
This means that my text, and my property, is updated only if I reload the page.

I've followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12099094/1094430) to fix this problem and having my `SearchQuery` update everytime that the text changes (and not only when it loses focus!) but it still won't work.

Here's my `TextBox` code:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding SearchQuery, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <utils:UpdateSourceOnTextChangedBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

and here's the attached behavior:

```
public class UpdateSourceOnTextChangedBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= OnTextChanged;
    }

    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    }
}
```

The funny thing is that it actually does what it has to do, because the `AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();` gets called everytime I change a character in my `TextBox`.

Of course the `SearchQuery` property raises all the needed events:

```
/// <summary>
/// Query used to search in the API
/// </summary>
private string _searchQuery;
public string SearchQuery
{
    get
    {
        return _searchQuery;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_searchQuery == value) return;
        _searchQuery = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SearchQuery);
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => CanSearch);                
        SearchCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
return _searchCommand ?? new RelayCommand(ExecuteSearch, () => CanSearch);
```

doesn't set the _searchCommand field. Perhaps making a new RelayCommand is messing something up?

Try this instead:

```
 return (_searchCommand != null) ? _searchCommand : _searchCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteSearch, () => CanSearch);
```

This lazily creates and sets _searchCommand correctly.

Comment: From my understanding, this should mean something like `if (_searchCommand == null) { _searchCommand = new RelayCommand(..); } return _searchCommand` so it should create a new `Command` only if it doesn't exists yet.

Comment: Nope, it means `if (_searchCommand != null) return _searchCommand; else return new RelayCommand(ExcecuteSearch, () => CanSearch;`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: @StepTNT: I think this is what you want: return (_searchCommand != null) ? _searchCommand : _searchCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteSearch, () => CanSearch);