# Windows Phone TextBox raise command RaiseCanExecuteChanged on TextChanged?

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8

I have a text box and a button that's bound to a property in my view model as follows

```
<TextBox  Text="{Binding UserName, Mode=TwoWay}"  />

<Button  Content="Log In"  Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
```

My UserName property:

```
private string userName;
        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.userName;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref userName, value);
                ((DelegateCommand)(this.LoginCommand)).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
```

The login command:

```
LoginCommand = new DelegateCommand(User_Login, Can_Login);
```

and the **Can_Login** method:

```
private bool Can_Login(object arg)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
```

My problem is that login button is always enabled untill the user name text box is not empty and **has lost focus**.

What I want to do is to make the button become enabled once the user types some text in the TextBox instantly without having the TextBox to lose focus.

is there a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to play with `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of binding. TextBox has it set to `LostFocus` event by default, hence `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` was called after that event in this case. In WPF, we can set it to `PropertyChanged`. With that setting `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` will be raised immediately after text property value changed, without waiting for `LostFocus` event :

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding UserName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Unfortunately, `PropertyChanged` isn't available in silverlight for windows phone. We need to use `Explicit` and raise binding UpdateSource event manually upon `TextChanged` event raised :

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding UserName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" 
        TextChanged="OnTextChanged"/>

//in code-behind
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    BindingExpression bindingExpr = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
    //Manually call UpdateSource
    bindingExpr.UpdateSource();
}
```

Note that code-behind in this case is fine (from MVVM pont-of-view), because it is just doing some UI/binding related tasks, not data related tasks.

References :

- ["UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" equivalent for a Windows Phone 7 TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833100/updatesourcetrigger-propertychanged-equivalent-for-a-windows-phone-7-textbox)
- [Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for me, maybe wrapping this functionality in a custom control will make it easier