# ApplicationBar click/tap event don't update input text/pasword boxes

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, application-bar

**Facts :**

1. phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar don't change the focused element.
2. TextBox/PasswordBox is changeing its binded content when losing focus

So if a user is writing something in a TextBox and he click a shell:ApplicationBarIconButton then the TextBox.Text={Binding ...} is not updated.

I found this solution:

http://www.pedrolamas.com/2013/01/11/how-to-force-a-focused-textbox-binding-to-update-when-i-tap-an-app-bar-item/

But c'mon I have 20 screens with inputs, it feels like reinventing the wheel again and again!

I search for a nice/cleaner solution if there is such.
Now I have to go across all click events where inputs are involved and put the magic line:

```
App.FocusedTextBoxUpdateSource();
```

Can it be set globally somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could create a custom textbox control with its text changed property bound to a command something that builds over this thread

["UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" equivalent for a Windows Phone 7 TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833100/updatesourcetrigger-propertychanged-equivalent-for-a-windows-phone-7-textbox)

Comment: yes! that's way better than remembering to force every AppBar to update inputs